# Output Select Query To CSV File

Tags: sql, oracle, csv, batch-file

I have an automated job set up as a .bat file. It runs a number of sql files and executes the code. I am having issues with outputting the results into a file. It is not outputting the headings and not displaying all results (instead of some zeros, it is showing blanks). 
I am using this code:

.bat file:

```
sqlplus -s %CONNECT% @createCSV.sql  > Weekly_Report%date:~0,2%%date:~3,2%%date:~6,4%.xls
```

createCSV.sql file:

```
set echo off
set verify off
set termout on
set heading off
set pages 50000
set feedback off
set newpage none
set linesize 1000
set serveroutput off
set pagesize 0
set trimout on
set trimspool on



select   query_date||','||online||','||cann||','||all
from     tmp_report_auto;


exit
```

Comment: the o/p file is csv or xls?

Comment: CSV, but I am happy to change!

Comment: you can get headers using `select 'field1,field2,......' from dual` just before the actual query. And change the o/p format to .csv.

Comment: You should turn `set heading on` and maybe add `set embedded on`